# why does this method take off the last letter in the string?

Tags: java, eclipse

This is part of a java project, we have to take in a sentence that has multiple spaces between the world (`a   sentence  like     this`) and convert it into a character array, then print out the sentence without all the extra spaces. It works, but it prints out the sentence missing the last letter.
**Sentence Class:**

```
public class sentences {
    
    String sentence;
    int length;
    private char[] ch;
    
    public sentences(String sentence, int length) {
        this.sentence = sentence;
        this.length = length;
        char [] ch;
    }

    /**method that takes a string and turns it into an array then prints out the array
     * makes an empty string and fills it with the char, takes out empty spaces
     * 
     */
    
    public char[] makesentenceanarray(String sentence, int length) {
        char[] ch = new char[sentence.length()];
        //String noWhite = "";
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        char prevchar = ' ';
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            ch[i] = sentence.charAt(i);
        }     
         for(int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++) {
             char currentchar = ch[j];
             
             if( !(prevchar == ' ' && currentchar == prevchar)) {
                 s.append(prevchar);
                
             }
             prevchar = currentchar;
         }
         
         s.deleteCharAt(0);
        
        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.print(s);
        return ch;      

            
        }
        
    }
```

**Tester class:**

import java.util.Scanner;

public class tester {

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("enter your sentence: ");
    
    String a = scan.nextLine();

    sentences s1 = new sentences(a, a.length());
    s1.makesentenceanarray(a, a.length());
        
    }
```

}

```
********************************************************************************
heres what I end up with:


enter your sentence: this  is   my    sentence
this  is   my    sentence 
this is my sentenc
```

any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After the loop, append `prevchar`. Also, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: thanks i changed it to string builder, last character keeps getting cut off though, I might be using stringbuilder incorrectly

Comment: @Skier1999 Don't forget to do `s.append(prevchar)` **after** the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You’re appending the previous character. Think instead about the circumstances under which you would append the current character. In you loop you will look at every current character, but for the very last character, the previous will be the second to last character and then the loop stops. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

sentence.length() starts counting at 1. (Yes I know it's inconsistent :D)Therefore you need to start counting at 1 and compare with <= at the first for loop.

```
 public char[] makesentenceanarray(String sentence, int length) {
        char[] ch = new char[sentence.length()];
        //String noWhite = "";
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        char prevchar = ' ';
        for (int i = 1; i <= sentence.length(); i++) {
            //you should do this now bc of the change of the for loop: 
            //ch[i - 1] = sentence.charAt(i - 1);
            ch[i] = sentence.charAt(i);
        }     
         for(int j = 0; j < sentence.length(); j++) {
             char currentchar = ch[j];
             
             if( !(prevchar == ' ' && currentchar == prevchar)) {
                 s.append(prevchar);
                
             }
             prevchar = currentchar;
         }
         //Now you should be able to delete this
         //s.deleteCharAt(0);
        
        System.out.println(ch);
        System.out.print(s);
        return ch;      

            
        }
        
    }
```